How to Trigger 1-Click Facebook OAuth Consent Dialog Instead of Multi-Step Flow
I'm attempting to use Meta's OAuth login for a project, however, the dialog is always a complex multi-step process. Several other sites have a simple, 1-click dialog. I noticed that whether I use the SDK or url, it ends up being the same result. Additionally, the url for the 1-click dialog is much longer and always starts with "https://www.facebook.com/privacy/consent/gdp/?params%5Bapp_id%".
1-click Dialog
Multi-step Dialog
Ss there any way to get the simpler login dialog on my end, or is it up to Meta?
I tried using both the SDK and a manual login with differing login settings. I also tried adding and removing scopes as well as all the possible auth_types to no avail. I also am testing in live mode/production.
